# Fetch Data from FormData in Javascript and handle in Golang

Tags: javascript, go

i'm trying to fetch some data from a HTML Webpage via Javascript to my Golang Webserver. But the Data does'nt seem to be received there.

This is my Javascript Function, which is called, when selecting something in my dropdown menu of my webpage:

```
async function onDataFormatSelect(dataFormat) 
    {
      console.log('Change DataFormat', dataFormat);
      let formDataSelect = new FormData();
      formDataSelect.append("cmd", "change");
      const fetchoptions  = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formDataSelect,
      };

      let r = await fetch('/myURL', fetchoptions);
      console.log('HTTP response code.', r.status);
      for (var pair of formDataSelect.entries()) {
        console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
      }
    }
```

In SetupRoutes() in my Go Webserver, the URL gets an Handler:

```
    http.HandleFunc("/myURL", urlHandler)
```

This is my Handler:

```
func urlHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    

    if r.Method == "POST" {
        r.ParseForm()

        topicName := r.FormValue("topicName")
        cmd := r.FormValue("cmd")
        log.Println("action: " + cmd)
        switch cmd {
        ...
        case "change": //Change DataFormat of Topic
            log.Println("cmd is " + cmd)
            newDataFormat := r.FormValue("dataFormat")
            //Call another function
        default:
            log.Println("unknown command: " + cmd)
        }

    } else {
        log.Println("using wrong method (GET)")
    }

    http.Redirect(w, r, appdata.Status.ProxyRedirect, http.StatusMovedPermanently)
}
```

The Output of Javascript is correct. The FormDataSelect is filled correctly, but in Go the "cmd" is not there. Somehow in another Function with the same setup everything is working correctly.

Can you help me or do you have any Workaround for me beside using XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: potentially you need to set the proper content type on the client side as header.

Comment: @TheFool — No. `fetch` will set the Content-Type header automatically based on the content. For `FormData` objects it will set it to be multipart and will get the mandatory `boundary` parameter which we can't predict from the code.

Comment: Do you have a source to that? Automatically setting content type?

Comment: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#bodyinit-unions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FormData objects are designed to support posting files so they *always* send multipart requests.

See the documentation for [Go's http module](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/).

You're using `parseForm` which says:

> when the Content-Type is not application/x-www-form-urlencoded, the request Body is not read, and r.PostForm is initialized to a non-nil, empty value

You need to use `ParseMultipartForm` instead.

Comment: Which maxMemory parameter do i have to give ParseMultipartForm? I just gave it 200 and it worked. But thats not very beautiful.

Comment: Depends on how big  your requests are and how much memory your server has. Since you only seem to be sending a string, "not much". 200 bytes is probably small even for that. 1000000 is one megabyte, which should be plenty for any request not actually uploading files.